# "File" command error - how to update magic file

Tags: file, terminal, command

I have been using the "file" command in terminal (Mac) for a while.

Now encountering this error:
file: File 5.31 supports only version 14 magic files. `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc' is version 13

Seems like a fairly simple solution to update the magic file, but can't find any instructions to complete this. Can someone advise?

Any help is much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have more than one **`file`** executable in your `$PATH`.  It can get confused if it finds a different database (magic) than it expected.  File 5.29 (tagged October 2016) bumped the format to version 14.  File 5.31 appears to be the current version on MacOS (works for me).

The "magic" file is built up from many smaller files (see [git repository *(mirror)*](https://github.com/file/file/tree/master/magic/Magdir)).  If you needed a specific version that's not prepackaged, you could download the source and compile it, starting with the [project page](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/), which points to an [ftp site](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/).

However, replacing that `magic.mgc` file runs into Apple's ["system protection"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) (limited permissions).  It's possible to turn that off (perhaps not a *Good Idea*®) But it's doable.

While you could replace the data file, it might be simpler to just install MacPorts and use the `file` package from that.  It's currently at 5.32 (a step ahead of Apple's package), and if you did not like that, it's simpler to remove/alter.