# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scheduler'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, pip, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Django REST API on GCP on Ubuntu 20.04 .I have created a virtual environment for my project. When I run pip3 python3.8 manage.py on my project path I'm getting the following error.

```html
python3.8 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 228, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scheduler'
```

Result of the pip list

> asgiref               3.5.2
> async-timeout         4.0.2
> backports.zoneinfo    0.2.1
> certifi               2022.5.18.1
> chardet               3.0.4
> Click                 7.0
> colorama              0.4.4
> colorlog              4.0.2
> cursor                1.3.4
> cycler                0.11.0
> Deprecated            1.2.13
> Django                4.0.4
> django-appconf        1.0.5
> django-cacheops       6.0
> django-cuser          2017.3.16
> django-imagekit       4.1.0
> django-media-fixtures 1.0.0
> django-nose           1.4.7
> django-ordered-model  3.5
> django-redis          5.2.0
> django-replicated     2.7
> django-rq             2.5.1
> django-storages       1.12.3
> django-tinymce        3.4.0
> djangorestframework   3.13.1
> fonttools             4.33.3
> funcy                 1.17
> halo                  0.0.28
> icalendar             4.0.9
> idna                  2.8
> kiwisolver            1.4.2
> log-symbols           0.0.14
> matplotlib            3.5.2
> modeltranslation      0.25
> nose                  1.3.7
> numpy                 1.22.4
> packaging             21.3
> pandas                1.4.2
> pilkit                2.0
> Pillow                9.1.1
> pip                   20.0.2
> pkg-resources         0.0.0
> pyparsing             3.0.9
> python-dateutil       2.8.2
> python-dotenv         0.20.0
> pytz                  2022.1
> pytz-deprecation-shim 0.1.0.post0
> redis                 4.3.1
> requests              2.22.0
> rq                    1.10.1
> scipy                 1.8.1
> sentry-sdk            1.5.12
> setuptools            44.0.0
> six                   1.16.0
> spinners              0.0.24
> sqlparse              0.4.2
> termcolor             1.1.0
> tzdata                2022.1
> tzlocal               4.2
> urllib3               1.25.11
> wheel                 0.34.2
> wrapt                 1.14.1

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you display what is the result of pip list?

Comment: Hello. pip list added

Comment: Are you running this in a Cloud Compute VM?
Have you tried `pip install scheduler`?

Comment: @Rogelio gcp vm yes in a virtual environment. tried the above pip command as well.

Comment: I downgraded to python 3.8 and error isnt there now. I have only this 1 error now - I would be grateful if you could help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350297/magicexception-file-5-39-supports-only-version-16-magic-file-magic-mgc-is-ver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with other interpreter path. It solved the problem for me. Here you can see, what I done with the help of VsCode:
[Click here for pic #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI1Nl.png)
[And here for pic #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Ljk.png)

I hope it works for you, too!

Comment: This worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
python3.8 -m pip install APScheduler
```

Comment: Tried the above David. Still getting the same error. I've also updated the question by adding pip list of packages installed.

Comment: could you please try again?

Comment: Yup david. tried again. the package installed successfully, however on running migrate.py I get the same error.

Comment: Any workaround for this ?

Comment: I downgraded to python 3.8 and error isnt there now. I have only this 1 error now - I would be grateful if you could help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350297/magicexception-file-5-39-supports-only-version-16-magic-file-magic-mgc-is-ver